# How do you create a boarder in an SSRS Report?

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, border, hidden, row-number

I've gotten the hang of creating charts/colors and grouping data but I can't seem to figure out how to outline each grouping in my report.

[image]

I've got data built for my chart - what I would like to have it appear as -- is like this:

[image]

I'm not picky on the color, but that's the least of my worries. I can't figure out how to create the outline, but by group rather then by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your **TOP Border Style**, use the expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!TourDate.Value = PREVIOUS(Fields!TourDate.Value), "None", "Solid")
```

This just checks to see if your **TourDate** field is different from the Previous row.

The default would need to be **solid**. You can use it with the border color (black) instead if you want the grey border normally.

Comment: This was a good start, I had to finagle things a bit but this definitely helped.